# How to send custom parameter for fetching data using datatables with server side paggination

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, datatable

I am using datatables for fetcing the data from the controller but the issue is that i have to pass some additional parameter for getting the record from the db but the issue is that when i use the sAjaxSource in the datatable request it automatically send all the parameter with the requst like pagination size , columns and sorting and other details without even mentioning it anywhere but when i use the explict ajax request like this.

```
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        data: {accountID : "45d4f5d4f5d"}
    }
```

it only send this parameter which is mentioned in the data and doesn't send other parameter which get sent by default when the request is made using sAjaxSource.

when i send the request like this it works:

```
       $(function () {
            var tableTemplates = $('#Voicemailtable').DataTable({

                sAjaxSource: "@Url.Action("VoicemailList", "Voicemail")",
                serverSide: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                bProcessing: true,
                processing: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: null, // <-- This is index column
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "context",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false


                    },
                    {
                        data: "created",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return moment(data).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        data: "guid",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        data: "mailbox",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        data: "password",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        data: "uniqueid",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    }
                ]
            });
            tableTemplates.on('draw.dt',
                function () {
                    var PageInfo = $('#Voicemailtable').DataTable().page.info();
                    tableTemplates.column(0, { page: 'current' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                        cell.innerHTML = i + 1 + PageInfo.start;
                    });
                });

        });
```

```
    public ActionResult VoicemailList(JqueryDatatableRequestModel model,string accountId)
         {
            var totalRecords = 0;
            var voicemails = voicemailService.GetVoicemailsListByAccountId(accountId, name: model.sSearch, totalCount: out totalRecords, recordStart: model.iDisplayStart, pageSize: model.iDisplayLength);
            var finalResults = Mapper.Map<List<VoicemailModel>>(Voicemails);
            return Json(new
            {
                model.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = totalRecords,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRecords,
                aaData = finalResults
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`
```

but when i try to add the additonal parameter it doesnt work

```
      $(function () {

            var table = $('#Voicemailtable').DataTable();
            var sEcho = table.settings()[0].oAjaxData.sEcho;
            var sSearch = table.search();
            var iDisplayLength = table.page.len();
            var iDisplayStart = table.page.info().start;
            var iSortCol_0 = table.order()[0][0];
            var sSortDir_0 = table.order()[0][1];

            var tableTemplates = $('#Voicemailtable').DataTable({

                sAjaxSource: "@Url.Action("VoicemailList", "Voicemail")",
                serverSide: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                bProcessing: true,
                processing: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("VoicemailList", "Voicemail")',
                    type: "Get",
                    data: {
                        accountId: "45454-df454-f4d65f4d54f"
                        sEcho: sEcho,
                        sSearch: sSearch,
                        iDisplayLength: iDisplayLength,
                        iDisplayStart: iDisplayStart,
                        iSortCol_0: iSortCol_0,
                        sSortDir_0: sSortDir_0
                    },
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: null, // <-- This is index column
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "context",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false


                    },
                    {
                        data: "created",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return moment(data).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        data: "guid",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        data: "mailbox",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        data: "password",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        data: "uniqueid",
                        sortable: false,
                        autoWidth: false
                    }
                ]
            });
            tableTemplates.on('draw.dt',
                function () {
                    var PageInfo = $('#Voicemailtable').DataTable().page.info();
                    tableTemplates.column(0, { page: 'current' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                        cell.innerHTML = i + 1 + PageInfo.start;
                    });
                });

        });
```

I tried making request from different pattern but its not working if someone could guide my it would be really appriciated.

Comment: Use the `function()` syntax of the `data` option. That allows you to add your custom data to the data provided automatically by DataTables when using `serverSide: true`.  See the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) and look at the examples `"data": function ( d ) { ... }`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data parameter using AJAX to PHP for server side processing in datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582317/pass-data-parameter-using-ajax-to-php-for-server-side-processing-in-datatables)

Comment: When i use the 
ajax: {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("VoicemailList", "Voicemail")",
                    "data": function (d) {
                        d.accountId = 2015;
                    }
                },
it only passes the mentioned parameter and all the default values like page number and etc don't get passed they appear as null in the controller

Comment: If you add `console.log(d);` to the function as its final statement, what do you see in the browser console? I see all of the server-side parameters (`draw`, `start`, `length`...) with their expected non-null values, plus your new parameter: `accountId: 2015` - also as expected. If that is not what you see, then I think there is some other problem, not shown in your question.

Comment: Just as a side-note, I recommend using POST not GET for this type of Ajax call. Send the data in the request body, not as a query string. This is not related to your problem - just an observation/suggestion.

Comment: You are right I am getting the values when I console.log(d) but the values are showing null in the controller I think I have to manually map the properties to model properties of the model I am using in the controller.
which is  mentioned above in the question JqueryDatatableRequestModel.

Comment: OK - so that is "how to send custom parameter" - which was the question being asked. If you are having a problem processing that data on the server, when it receives the request, I think that is a new/different question. By default, the payload will be formatted as form URL-encoded data.

Comment: Yes, that is the real issue, so how do I do that in a controller what would be the optimal way?

Comment: I think that is a completely new/different question. I'm sure there must already be many answers on Stack Overflow for how to read form data in a ASP.Net controller. Or you can convert the data to JSON in your data function and send JSON instead of form data, I suppose (if you prefer).

Comment: Alright, I got that.